# As I use python to import dlib after successfully installing it in anaconda, it shows an error

Tags: python, dynamic, dll, hyperlink, dlib

After installing dlib in anaconda in a unique and newly created environment when I import it using python like

> > python
> > import dlib
> > it returns an error like shown

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\py36dlib\lib\site-packages\dlib_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

> > > import dlib
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\py36dlib\lib\site-packages\dlib_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
> > > from _dlib_pybind11 import *
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Comment: You should probably provide some context.

Comment: Alright, Andre Reichelt, so I am working on a face recognition system using machine learning and I need dlib for that. I made a new environment in anaconda just for dlib then I installed dlib in that environment and it was installed successfully without any error. Now to make sure it was correctly installed I used python and imported dlib at that time it showed the error shown above. I have tried downgrading dlib to 19.19 version but that also doesn't work and shows same error.

Comment: The error is >>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing dlib: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Comment: Hi
And how did You resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this it might be that your cpu doesnt support AVX so I install tensorflow from this custommade repository found on github link is [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel)

I selected 1.12.0 for py 37 in that folder select py36 folder and cpu folder and download the file within sse2

cpu which doesn support download sse2 whl

Comment: Hi, Revisto I have found that the avx supported cpu were introduced in 2011 and my cpu was introduced in 2014. So I don't think that is the problem.