# Conda&dlib: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, anaconda, dlib

I see similar (really the same) questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578587/as-i-use-python-to-import-dlib-after-successfully-installing-it-in-anaconda-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224572/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-internala-dynam). But nothing proposed is working for me... So I work in:

- Windows10
- CUDA10.1
- Anaconda
- Python 3.8

All I did - create env and install dlib:

```
(dlib) C:\Users\Vasil>conda install dlib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Games\conda\envs\dlib

  added / updated specs:
    - dlib


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  dlib               conda-forge/win-64::dlib-19.21.1-py38h082dfc2_0
  intel-openmp       conda-forge/win-64::intel-openmp-2020.3-h57928b3_311
  jpeg               conda-forge/win-64::jpeg-9d-h8ffe710_0
  libblas            conda-forge/win-64::libblas-3.9.0-8_mkl
  libcblas           conda-forge/win-64::libcblas-3.9.0-8_mkl
  liblapack          conda-forge/win-64::liblapack-3.9.0-8_mkl
  libpng             conda-forge/win-64::libpng-1.6.37-h1d00b33_2
  mkl                conda-forge/win-64::mkl-2020.4-hb70f87d_311
  numpy              conda-forge/win-64::numpy-1.20.1-py38h0cc643e_0
  zlib               conda-forge/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_1010


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(dlib) C:\Users\Vasil>python
Python 3.8.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 20 2021, 15:50:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  
  File "D:\Games\conda\envs\dlib\lib\site-packages\dlib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

SO all having this problem have successful installation and never working **dlib**. Please help with this issue.